# Cómo enviar mensaje al front en laravel y seguir ejecutando la función y cuanto termine si enviar un return view()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, nginx

El código a continuación no es importante en cuanto a mi pregunta, pero si tiene que ver. El tema es que al hacer el respectivo request http a x servidor se puede llegar a demorar hasta un minuto, pero entonces me dará un error de Time exceed por parte de php y nginx, como puedo responder al front un mensaje diciendo que ya está en ejecución esta función y cuando ya termine definitivamente si enviar el return redirect() que se ve al final.

```
public function sendProperties(Request $request)
    {
        
        if(isset($request["company"])){
            $company = CompanyToken::where("company_id", $request["company"])->get();
        } else {
            $company = CompanyToken::where("company_id", $this->id_company)->get();
        }
        
        $props = Property::where("company_id", $company[0]["id"])->whereNull("send")->skip(0)->take(2)->get(); 

        if (count($props) != 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i <= sizeof($props) - 1; $i++) {

                $params = $this->getParams($props[$i]);
                
                if (sizeof($params) == 0) {
                    $changeState = Property::where('codpro', "{$props[$i]["codpro"]}")->first();
                    $changeState->send = "not send - no address";
                    $changeState->save();
                    continue;
                } else {
                    $res = $this->client->request("POST", "{$this->endpoint}/properties", [
                        "headers" => [
                            "Authorization" => $company[0]["domus_auth"]
                        ],
                        "form_params" => $params
                    ]);

                    $property = json_decode($res->getBody(), true);

                    if ($property["code"] == 200) {
                        $changeState = Property::where('codpro', "{$props[$i]["codpro"]}")->first();
                        $changeState->send = "send";
                        $changeState->send_at = date("d M Y H:i:s");
                        $changeState->save();
                    } else {
                        $changeState = Property::where('codpro', "{$props[$i]["codpro"]}")->first();
                        $changeState->send = "not send - error: " . $property["code"];
                        $changeState->save();
                    }
                }
            }
            return redirect()->route("index")->with("success", "Enviado");
        } else {
            return redirect()->route("index")->with("error", "No existen Propiedades para el envío");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer con javascript, simplemente con un evento onclick, cuando presionen cambias el estilo del mensaje de escondido a visible, no recuerdo bien la regla del css para eso, y simplemente el sistema se encarga de lo demas cuando termina el proceso

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: al final de esta respuesta menciono los server-sent events, que  funcionan parecido a un stream de video, en el sentido que la conexión no se cierra y el contenido de la respuesta va fluyendo de a poco. [En MDN hay un ejemplo usando PHP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events), pero [es más elegante usar la clase StreamedResponse de Symfony](https://dev.to/mesadhan/event-stream-server-send-events-5afk). Pueden servir para lo que quieres, pero ante la duda yo usaría jobs y notificaciones.

### Postulados que afectan a tu caso de uso

- Para que el backend pueda decirte: "estamos trabajando para usted", se enviará  antes que nada un status code.
- Si el status code indica redirección, será de la familia 300.
- Si, en cambio, indica éxito, pertenece a la familia 200.
- En particular, si quieres responder que el proceso se ha iniciado, pero sin tener seguridad de que haya concluido con éxito, ello se ajustaría al propósito del header [202 Accepted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/202):

> The request has been received but not yet acted upon. It is
> noncommittal, since there is no way in HTTP to later send an
> asynchronous response indicating the outcome of the request. It is
> intended for cases where another process or server handles the
> request, or for batch processing.

### Problemas derivados de lo anterior

**El primer problema** para lo que quieres hacer es que, enviada esta respuesta,  no hay instancia para enviar una segunda respuesta.  Primero porque no puedes retornar dos veces, y segundo porque si quisieras fijar manualmente el status y luego mandar la respuesta real

```
header("HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted");

header("Location: http://127.0.0.1:8080");
```

te saltaría un error: `headers already sent`.

**El segundo problema** es que,  si retornamos antes de terminar el proceso, éste nunca llegará a ejecutarse. Para lidiar con tu caso de uso lo que uno hace es "despachar una tarea", como se explica en la documentación de [los queues de Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues).

Pero olvídate de los queues: una tarea puede consistir en un simple closure, que puedes despachar usando `dispatchAfterResponse`. Es decir, que tenga lugar después de la respuesta. Esto es justo lo que quieres hacer (salvo la redirección final)

```
public function sendProperties(Request $request) {

      dispatch(function() use ($request) {
            if(isset($request["company"])){
            $company = CompanyToken::where("company_id", $request["company"])->get();
        } else {
            $company = CompanyToken::where("company_id", $this->id_company)->get();
        }
        
        $props = Property::where("company_id", $company[0]["id"])->whereNull("send")->skip(0)->take(2)->get(); 

        if (count($props) != 0) {
         // etc etc etc 
        }
      })->afterResponse();

      return response()->setStatusCode(202,'Tarea agendada');

}
```

**El tercer problema** es que el acto de retornar un objeto `response` desde dentro de este closure no tendrá ningún efecto. Para informar al usuario del resultado final, en general se recurre a una [notificación](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/notifications), por el canal que sea: websockets, como pusher, o un simple email, o en realidad por el canal que quieras, porque el paquete [Laravel Notification Channels](https://laravel-notification-channels.com/about/#suggesting-a-new-channel) tiene adaptadores para todo: desde slack hasta SMS, pasando por palomas mensajeras y recados de la vecina chismosa. Te dejo encaminado en esa dirección por si quieres seguir ese camino, pero no pretendo entrar a escribir un tutorial sobre notificaciones en laravel.

### Respuestas a preguntas que nadie hizo, by ffflabs

**P:** ¿No es inconsistente responder con 202, considerando que la familia 200 indica éxito, y no tenemos cómo predecir un resultado exitoso?

**R:** Es común encontrarse con implementaciones que usan los status codes de mala manera. Responden 404 cuando, usando la ruta correcta, pides un modelo que no existe. En realidad 404 correspondería a pedir una ruta que no exista. En este caso el status code no se pronuncia sobre lo que hagas en el método. Solamente indica que tu request "entró" en él.

---

**P:** ¿Hay excepciones al concepto de la paridad 1:1 entre request y response?

**R:** Sí hay. No como para forzar dos respuestas 200, sino para casos de uso específico.

- Websockets: para empezar, el browser preguntará si el servidor soporta websockets. Éste responderá con un header `101 Upgrade` y ello no  dará lugar al término de la comunicación, sino que ésta se "upgradea" a un canal bidireccional permanente. Los websockets se ocupan, por ejemplo, para los chats de soporte, o la edición colaborativa de documentos.
- [Early Hints](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/early-hints/). Esta es una tecnología experimental y está soportada por menos de la quinta parte de los navegadores. Lo bueno es que esa quinta parte es Chrome así que representa como el 90% del tráfico web. Viene a ser el reemplazo de HTTP2 Push, que Chrome dejará de soportar. Los early hints se envían aparejados al header 103, y sirven para sugerir al browser los assets que sería eficiente cargar en paralelo para optimizar la velocidad. Este caso de uso por lo que entiendo sí permite enviar dos status codes. En la imagen siguiente se muestra un sitio que, al pedir el index.html, te dice: "dame unos segundos para armar mi landing page, te sugiero descargar la hoja de estilos por mientras". Si el browser toma en cuenta la sugerencia, se gatillará un segundo request.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- [Server-sent events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events): es como el websocket de los pobres, en la forma de un canal unidireccional permanente. Cuando la respuesta del servidor viene con el header `Content-Type: text/event-stream` El browser no cierra la comunicación, y de paso gatillará un evento cada vez que el servidor imprima contenido nuevo. A lo mejor serviría

---

**P:** Por qué se está descontinuando HTTP2 Push?

**R:** Porque no cumplía su propósito. En vez de limitarse a empujar los assets relevantes, no faltó el sitio que empujaba proactivamente su galería de fotos HD completa.